# How to do community detection in a Web Graph stored in Neo4j

Tags: algorithm, neo4j, graph-algorithm

I have created a crawler for a service. I would like to automatically detect regions/ communities in websites. I have made a model where an url links to another url in case of an href (`:LinksTo`). When there's a link back I also create an extra relationship called `:Connected`.

I would like to which communities exist and how big they are. The problem is I keep ending up with 1 huge community, and a small number tiny communities. I am kind of stuck here.

I have installed the these algorithms: https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-graph-algorithms/ and I tried to do something with triangle counts and the clustercoefficient, but creating nice partitions of nodes seems impossible.

Anyone an idea?

Comment: I am trying to find overlaps at this moment. If large portion of a from node (from)-[:linksto]-(to) overlaps with (somenode)-[:linksto]-(to) I guess the first from will be part of the hierarchy of home-somenode-from. I have already tried something like (child:Url)-[:linksTo]->(deeper:Url)<-[:Linksto]-(:parent) WHERE child.outGoing < parent.outGoing. I have a 13k size graph, and the query above takes forever. Does anyone have a better idea? The outGoing count is something I think should be correct in webgraphs, as all pages have a set of links they all have (give or take some with other design)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you have tried LPA and Louvain community detection. One way to avoid getting to one big community and some small ones using above algorithms is limiting the iterations.

Another thing that you can do is to try to define a similarity threshold for relationships, so that for example two website must have at least 5 common connections or they are not regarded similar(drops relationship between them).

Check [this blog series](https://tbgraph.wordpress.com/category/marvel/) for more detailed information.

What is also documented in these series is `apoc.periodic.iterate`, that can help you infer the network you are describing in the comment section, so that you can easily play around with it. In your case the statement would be something along the lines of. This will infer and store a weighted network to help you find those very similar websites.

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
"MATCH  (child:Url)-[:linksTo]->(deeper:Url)<-[:Linksto]-(:parent) 
where id(child) < id(parent) 
RETURN p1,p2
","
MERGE (p1)-[r:SIMILAR]-(p2) 
ON CREATE SET r.weight = 1 
ON MATCH SET r.weight = r.weight + 1"
,{batchSize:5000, parallel:false,iterateList:true})
```

Comment: Thanks. Never thought of making nodes similar with an extra relation.